# Windows desktop widget to turn proxy on and off

Tags: windows, proxy, widget

I want to make a simple Windows desktop widget to turn on and off the internet proxy.

What is the simpler way?

Comment: More options are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439373/batch-file-to-disable-internet-options-proxy-server

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a simple "widget" using Visual Basic scripts and batchs.

Example:

proxy_off.bat

```
echo off
cls
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
change_shortcut_on
exit
```

proxy_on.bat

```
echo off
cls
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
change_shortcut_off
exit
```

change_shortcut_off.vbs

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Proxy.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\proxy_off.bat"
shortcut.IconLocation = "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\Icons\on.ico"
shortcut.Save
```

change_shortcut_on.vbs

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Proxy.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\proxy_on.bat"
shortcut.IconLocation = "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\Icons\off.ico"
shortcut.Save
```

Instructions:

- Create the folder "Proxy Settings" in "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\";
- Create the folder "Icons" in "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\";
- Insert the "on.ico" (any icon for proxy "On") and "off.ico" (any icon for proxy "Off") in "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\Icons";
- Create the above files in "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\" (proxy_off.bat, proxy_on.bat, change_shortcut_off.vbs, change_shortcut_on.vbs);
- Create a shortcut (Proxy.lnk) to "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\proxy_off.bat" in your Desktop;

Done! Very simple and effective.
Now you can click on "Proxy.lnk" (the shortcut in your Desktop) to turn your proxy "On" and "Off".

Proxy On         Proxy Off

[image: Proxy On]           [image: Proxy Off]

On icon url: http://s30.postimg.org/sgoerz0od/image.png
Off icon url: http://s13.postimg.org/9zha38zkj/off.png

Comment: Also, make sure your .bat are not set to open by default with notepad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905708/batch-files-dont-run-theyre-being-opened-with-notepad. I also set the `shortcut.WorkingDirectory="C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings" `to run the vbs programs and set a variable for the environmental variable `user=sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")` to use in the path names

Comment: Important: `%USERNAME%` can NOT be used in the path names. I get the following error (image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbA5P.png). Instead, type out the actual folder name in place of that--ex: `gabriel`. Make sure you replace `%USERNAME%` *everywhere* it appears. Ex: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Proxy Settings\proxy_off.bat` --> `C:\Users\gabriel\Proxy Settings\proxy_off.bat` for me.

Comment: I can't get the icon to show up either. It's just a white square. I even tried converting the png images above to .ico files using http://icoconvert.com/

Comment: @Lucas NN, I took it one step further. Also, I ran into several errors implementing your answer, and have resolved them here. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752679/4561887. I have it creating a desktop shortcut and modifying the icon according to the Proxy state, using only one single .vbs file and no batch files, as well as bringing up a 1 sec timed popup windows to announce the new state each time you click the desktop shortcut. Thanks for your work. You were half the equation.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 it seams that after execute the script you need to open proxy settings window for changes to take effect. 
So add the following lines:

**proxy_off.bat**

```
echo off
cls
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
change_shortcut_on
start /min ms-settings:network-proxy
taskkill /IM SystemSettings.exe /f
exit
```

**proxy_on.bat**

```
echo off
cls
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
change_shortcut_off
start /min ms-settings:network-proxy
taskkill /IM SystemSettings.exe /f
exit
```

ATM the setting window don`t start minimized.

Answer (score 1):

Although this solution doesn't toggle the settings on its own, but it may be a shortcut to go to the right place quickly.

In windows 10 you can add a shortcut on your desktop, and in location field you enter:

```
ms-settings:network-proxy
```

This will direct you to the toggle proxy button. You then just need to click save.