# Task Scheduler loads script into editor instead of running it

Tags: windows-10, autoit, taskscheduler

My AutoIt script that executes from Windows Task Scheduler under Windows 7 works fine. On my Windows 10 machine with the identical task, instead of running the script, the Task Scheduler loads it into SciTE (an editor that accompanies AutoIt).

When I execute the script from within Explorer it runs. When I execute it from a command line it runs. It's only from Task Scheduler that I get this misbehavior. How do you tell Task Scheduler I want to *run* the script, not edit it?

Comment: you can [set the default action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43068749/2152082).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not wish to compile it, you can pass the script name to the AutoIt executable. For example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoIt3.exe" "C:\Scripts\Test.au3"
```

This is how it would look in Task Scheduler:

[image]

And you can read more about AutoIt command line switches at this
[online help page](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm#CommandLine).

Comment: Sidenote: Always make sure to set `Start in (optional)` in case to avoid errors. You can get in trouble if your script creates temporarly files.

Comment: This solution, and compiling the script, both work. It's just a shame that Microsoft took something that worked fine under Windows 7 and broke it for Windows 10, making workarounds necessary.